# Error in running Spring-Boot Application on Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I tried to run my simple Spring Web application jar on docker but I always get the following error. ubuntu & openjdk images exist and their state is UP. I could not run my jar file on docker? How can I get rid of this error?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-5:~/jar$ **docker run -d -p 8080:8080 spring-docker tail -f /dev/null**
c8eb92e5315adbaccfd894ed9e74b8e0d0eed88a81eaa07037cf8ada133c81fd
docker: **Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**

Related DockerFile:

FROM ubuntu
FROM openjdk

VOLUME /tmp
ADD /spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with below sequence  which works for me.

Build image using below command.

```
docker build -t demo-img .
```

DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

then run like below.

```
docker run --name demo-container -d -p 8080:8080 demo-img
```

**Make sure you are running all these command from the directory in which DockerFile and jar is present.**

Comment: The concerned error was fixed but the status of the container is no up. Dockerfile and the related jar file are in the same folder. Thanks for your help.